# Update existing database entry in java App

Tags: java, mysql

I am currently trying to make an update application (Java based) that the user can go through and view the existing database entries (MySQL) and edit them if need be... I was wondering how to get the information for a specific entry (ie 12-1589 which is an example of what the ID or primary key would be) and fill in the text boxes with all of the information from said entry.... I may just need to walk away from the computer for a bit because i may be over-thinking it, but I don't know...

mainly i am unsure with the exact code that you would use to move to that entry and retrieve the data from just that entry.... I know how to step trough a database one entry at a time, but i would rather just jump to a specific row based off of an id number (such as above 12-1589) if at all possible....

I just tried this and i recieved an error.... The error was:
 "Unknown column '12-1859' in 'where clause'"

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
stmt = con.createStatement();       
String sql = "SELECT * FROM Load_Sheet WHERE Load_Number = 12-1859 limit 1";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
String BC = rs.getString("BC");
```

If anyone could give me a hand with that is going wrong i would appreciate it...

I just started getting another error along with the other one... it is :
"illegal operation on empty result set"

Though the result sets are not empty so my guess is, is that i am missing a step somewhere....

Comment: I recommend you to learn more about relational databases, maybe from a senior member in your team.

Comment: Usually you'd start with a SQL statement that looks something like this: `SELECT * FROM my_table_name WHERE id = 42;` ...but you haven't shown any code, or mentioned _how_ you're talking to MySQL (JDBC? Hibernate?).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention what database connection i was using it is Mysql JDBC... @MДΓΓ БДLL I added some code that i tried and the error i got with it...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a simple `WHERE` statement if i understood correctly your question.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE entry_col = "12-1589" LIMIT 1
```

`LIMIT 1` is only added so that the `MySql` query only returns a single row.

Comment: so i am guessing it would look something like this....

do connection....

`stmt = con.createStatement();`
`String sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE entry_col = "12-1589" limit 1";`
'rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);`
`String ID_col = rs.getString("ID");`
`String data2 = rs.getString("other_Table_data");`
...... etc...